# Join multiple tables using substring match in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, join, pattern-matching

I have two tables in two different databases in postgres.

```
table1

id1   name1   col1
1     drug1   GLASDEGIB MALEATE
```

```
table2

id2   name2   col2
12    drug2   glasdegib
```

I am joining the two tables using below query

```
select table1.*, ob.* 

from    
    table1

left join (
                   SELECT *
                   FROM   dblink('dbname=x port=x host=x user=x password=x,
                                '
                                SELECT
                                    *
                                FROM
                                    table2
                                    ; 
                                '
                                ) AS ob (id2 int,
                                         name2 character varying,
                                         col2 character varying)
                ) AS ob ON table1.col1 ilike '%' || ob.col2|| '%'
```

```
The desired output is:
id1   name1   col1                 id2   col2   col2
1     drug1   GLASDEGIB MALEATE    12   drug2   glasdegib
```

But the above ilike is not working. How could I achieve the desired output?

Comment: I tried 'table1.col1 ilike '%' || ob.col2 || '%') or (ob.col2 ilike '%' || table1.col1  || '%''. It worked.

Comment: The query you show has unbalanced single quote marks.  Once that is fixed, it works.  The edit you show in your comment doesn't fix that problem, introduces more unbalanced/misplaced punctuation problems, and is unnecessary.